# Rolling apply lambda function based on condtion

Tags: pandas, lambda, conditional-statements, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with normalised (to 100) returns for 18 products (columns). I want to apply a lambda function which multplies the next row by the previous row.

I can do :

```
 df= df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: (x[0]*x[1]),raw=True)
```

But some of my columns dont have values on row 1 (they go live on row 4). So I need to either:

1. Have a lambda function that starts only on row 4 yet applies to the entire df. I can create the first 4 rows manually.
2. As my values are 100 until "live" I could have the lambda function only applying when the value does not equal 100.

I have tried both :

1.

```
df.iloc[3:,:] = df.iloc[3:,:].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: (x[0]*x[1]),raw=True)
```

2. 

```
   df= df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: (x[0]*x[1]) if x[0] != 100 else x,raw=True)
```

But both meet with total failure.

Any advice welcomed - I've spent hours looking through the site and have yet to find any outcome that works for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given the lack of responses I came up with a solution where I split my df in 2 parts and appended it back together.

My lambda function was also garbage I needed something like :

```
df2 = df.copy()
    for i in range(df2.index.size):
    if not i:
        continue
    df2.iloc[i] = (df2.iloc[i - 1] * (df.iloc[i])) 
df2
```

to actually achieve what I was after.